# Laravel View Composer

Tags: php, laravel

I'm following a tutorial for laravel and there is something that I don't understand. It's referred to using views composer.

1. -I have a template called from `app/http/routes.php` given an Url:

   `Route::get('cats/create', function(){return view('cats.create');});`

this is `cats/create.blade.php`:

> ```
> @extends('master')
> @section('header')
>   <h2> Add a new cat </h2>
> @stop
> @section('content')
> {!! Form::open(['url'=>'/cats']) !!}
>  @include('partials.forms.cat')
> {!! Form::close() !!}
> @stop
> ```

2. -This template includes another one (partial) which covers the HTML of a Form

   ```
   <div class="form-group">

    {!! Form::label('name','Name') !!}

    <div class="form-controls">

     {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    </div>

   </div>

   <div class="form-group">

    {!! Form::label('date_of_birth', 'Date of Birth') !!}

   <div class="form-controls">
     {!! Form::date('date_of_birth', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    </div>

   </div>

   <div class="form-group">

    {!! Form::label('breed_id','Breed') !!}

    <div class="form-controls">

    {!! Form::select('breed_id', $breeds, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!} 

    </div>

   </div>

   {!! Form::submit('Save Cat', ['class' => 'btn-primary']) !!}
   ```
3. -Now uses a view composer in order to automatically fullfill the select element when this partial view is called. In `AppServiceProvider`:

> ```
> public function boot(ViewFactory $view)
>     {
>       $view->composer('partials.forms.cat','Furbook\Http\Views\Composers\CatFormComposer');
> }
> ```

4.- And this is that `CatFormComposer`

```
class CatFormComposer
{
    protected $breeds;

    public function __construct(Breed $breeds)
    {
        $this->breeds = $breeds;
    }

    public function compose(View $view)  {
        $breeds = $this->breeds;
        $view->with('breeds', $breeds->lists('name', 'id'));
    }
}
```

It works. What I don't get is, How is that `$breeds` parameter being passed to the constructor of the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All View Composers are resolved by laravel service container. So when you type-hint **Breed $breeds** laravel will use [php reflection api](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to find the expected class and inject the instance of that class (in that case: Container will find Breed class , create **new Breed** and pass the instance on constructor).

Also for deeper understanding you can take look about [service locator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/service_locator_pattern.htm) pattern

Comment: Thank you, I see... Why can't they just declare and instantiate a var $breeds inside the constructor? Is not more readable?

Comment: It's follow the constructor injection to get some great benefits in the case of testing and loose coupling. if they instantiate it locally in the scope as you said this will make the testing of view composer hard without make sure that Breed class is properly implemented. On the other hand, constructor injection help us to mock the Breed implementation and Inject it through the constructor. At the end of the day it helps us to obey SOLID principle.